# Running RSPEC in Ruby + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to run `rspec` in my rails app using the `spec` command- but I get the following error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- spec/rails/example/helper_example_group_helper (LoadError)
```

I have had to deal already with missing 'helper' files, but it seems this one is not even in my app but in rails itself..
If I go ahead and create a `helper_example_group_helper.rb` file, then the error will appear regarding some other missing helper file inside Rails, ad infinitum.

The full log trace: http://pastie.org/pastes/3295692/text

The full gem list: http://pastie.org/pastes/3296070/text

I am running:

- Ruby 1.9.3-p0
- Rails 2.3.14
- rspec 1.2.9 (gem)
- rspec-rails 1.2.9 (gem)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: dude! rspec 1.2 is soooo old! use rspec 2.x!

Comment: wouldn't that force me to use rails 3? it's not possible unfortunately...

Comment: i don't think that you need it for 2.1 http://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-rails/versions/2.1.0

Comment: the link you sent explicitly states that Rails 3 is required for RSpec 2.x... :-(

Comment: äh, no?! the only dependency is rspec?! what are you looking at?!???!

Comment: RSpec 2.x is not supported with Rails 2. I just tried it.. again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old question but it's an issue I hit recently while upgrading a rails app. This issue is specific to Rails 2.3.x and ruby 1.9.3. There's a google groups thread about it here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyonrails-core/gb5woRkmDlk/iQ2G7jjNWKkJ%5B1-25%5D

The workaround is to add a file to `config/initializers` with the following:

```
MissingSourceFile::REGEXPS.push([/^cannot load such file -- (.+)$/i, 1])
```

Comment: This helped greatly as I try to upgrade a legacy app. Thanks.